# Android: exception when disconnecting from bluetooth device

Tags: android, bluetooth, try-catch

I'm looking for a way to gracefully disconnect from a Bluetooth device. I used the BluetoothChat sample and the problem is that when you intend to disconnect you simply call `socket.close()` from the `cancel()` method, but then the `IntputStream.read()` will inevitably throw an exception.

I need this mainly because it acts as a *"lost connection"* failsafe as well, so when I try to disconnect I get two signals: graceful disconnection followed by lost connection signal.

Basically what I'm trying to do is not to throw an exception in a method that will inevitably throw one:

```
while(true)
{
    try
    {
        bytes = 0;
        while((ch = (byte) inStream.read()) != '\0')
        {
            buffer[bytes++] = ch;
        }

        String msg = new String(buffer, "UTF-8").substring(0, bytes);
        Log.v(TAG, "Read: " + msg);

    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to read");
        // Inform the parent of failed connection
        connectionEnd(STATE_LOST);
        break;
    }
}
```

And the extremely egoistic `cancel()`:

```
public void cancel()
{
    try
    {
        socket.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

## EDIT

This is the error code I get when I `e.printStackTrace();` in `catch`:

```
09-06 13:05:58.557: W/System.err(32696): java.io.IOException: Operation Canceled
09-06 13:05:58.557: W/System.err(32696):    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readNative(Native Method)
09-06 13:05:58.557: W/System.err(32696):    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.read(BluetoothSocket.java:333)
09-06 13:05:58.557: W/System.err(32696):    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothInputStream.read(BluetoothInputStream.java:60)
09-06 13:05:58.557: W/System.err(32696):    at com.bluetooth.BluetoothRemoteControlApp$ConnectedThread.run(BluetoothRemoteControlApp.java:368)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**: it's not perfect, but since there's no way of stopping the exception I made a *disconnecting* condidition:

```
catch(IOException e)
{
    if(!disconnecting)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to read");
        e.printStackTrace();
        // Inform the parent of failed connection
        connectionEnd(STATE_LOST);
    }
    break;
}
```

`disconnecting` is set to `true` before calling the `cancel()` method. I'm not happy with it but it's not *that* ugly. I'm just not satisfied with the way the Bluetooth disconnection is handled (it works or it breaks).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Suppose you have *`out`* object of OutputStream and *`in`* object of InputStream, Then 
inside your cancel close the connection like this:

```
public void cancel()
{
    if(socket != null)
        {
            try {
                out.close();
                in.close();
                socket.getOutputStream().close();
                socket.close();
                socket = null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            }
        }
}
```

Hope this help you

Comment: This didn't help, I still get the `Failed to read` error on my log. Either there's a stupidly easy way to fix it or it's a major flaw, because there's a huge difference in losing and finishing a connection.

Comment: i was also facing this problem. so that finally i resolved this by overriding the onBackPressed() method ,removed super() from there and added this above complete code there. I know that is not the perfact solution. But i did it just for checking the flow. So if you want then you can use it just for checking.